# Prove a functions integral is greater than $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and suppose that $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x \in\ [a,b].$

Prove that if there exists a point $c \in\ [a,b]$ such that $f(c)>0$, then $$\int_{a}^b f(x)\,dx > 0 .$$

I feel like by proving this function is uniformly continuous, which is trivial, that it somehow shows me that the integral is greater than $0$, but I don't quite know how to get there. Can someone help?

Thanks! On a side note, I don't think the mathtex stuff came out right, let me know how to fix that!

Comment: The function is continuous - what does this imply about the set $\{x: f(x)>0\}$?

Answer (score 2):

let $c\in [a,b]$ : $f(c)>0$ then

from continuous we have

$\exists \delta >0 : \forall x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$  $\qquad f(x)>0$

now, we have

$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^{c-\delta} f(x)+\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} f(x)dx+\int_{c+\delta}^b f(x)d(x)\geq \int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} f(x)dx >0$

Comment: Do you mind explicitly saying how you concluded that $f(x) > 0$?  thanks

Comment: Is it because by definition of continuity we can choose $\varepsilon >0$ arbitrarily, so we can just choose it so that $f(x)>0$?

Comment: sorry to be annoying but it also is not clear to me how you went from $f(x)$ to $\int_a^b f(x) dx = ...$.  Can you (or someone) please explain that?

Obviously this is intuitively true, but most college-level math courses will require more rigor than that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $f$ be positive at the point $p$. Then by the definition of continuity, there is an interval about $p$ (one-sided if $p$ is an endpoint) such that $f(x)\gt f(p)/2$ in that interval. Thus the integral over that interval is positive. The integral(s) over the rest of $[a,b]$ are $\ge 0$. So the full integral over $[a,b]$ is positive.

The above sketch assumes that you have already proved that if $f\ge g$ on some interval $[c,d]$, then $\int_c^d f(x)\,dx \ge \int_c^d g(x)\,dx$. It also assumes the result that if $a\le c\le b$, then $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_a^c f(x)\,dx+\int_c^b f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: How would you formally prove the latter?