# Proving the existence of a variable with given condition in a function

Tags: functions, derivatives

I came across a problem of fucntions which is as follows:
f is a differentiable function $${f: [0,(\pi/2])\rightarrow[0,1] }$$
such that f(0)=0,  f$(\pi/2)=1$ then;  prove that $$f'(a)= (8a)/(\pi)^2 $$for at least one $a$ belonging to the domain.

I have tried using LMVT for the function between 0 and $(\pi/2)$ but that does not seem to help as $a$ should appear in the derivative. I could assume the function as sin x but that does not give me a general solution of course. I have no other idea on how to solve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure about $\frac{8a}\pi$. Isn't it $\frac{8a}{\pi^2}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, you are correct. I am editing the question now. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will solve the problem under the extra assumption that $f$ is continuously differentiable. And I shall used the follows lemma, whose proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/252809/446262):

**Lemma:** If $g\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow[0,\infty)$ is continuous and if $g(c)>0$ for some $c\in[a,b]$, then $\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx>0$.

Suppose that you always have $f'(a)\leqslant\frac{8a}{\pi^2}$ and that $f'(a)<\frac{8a}{\pi^2}$ for some $a$. Then\begin{align}1&=f\left(\frac\pi2\right)-f(0)\\&=\int_0^{\pi/2}f'(a)\,\mathrm da\\&<\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{8a}{\pi^2}\text{(by the lemma, applied to $\frac{8x}{\pi^2}-f'(x)$)}\\&=1,\end{align}which is impossible. By a similar argument, you can't have always $f'(a)\geqslant\frac{8a}{\pi^2}$ and $f'(a)>\frac{8a}{\pi^2}$ for some $a$. So, unless, $f'(a)$ is always equal to $\frac{8a}{\pi^2}$, $f'(a_1)<\frac{8a_1}{\pi^2}$ and $f'(a_2)>\frac{8a_2}{\pi^2}$ for some numbers $a_1,a_2\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$. Now, apply the intermediate value theorem to $f'$.

Comment: I would propose to explain the $<$ concerning the integral further, because $<$ at a point combined with $\leq$ elsewhere is not directly sufficient to show $<$ for the integral. (since $\{a\}$ is a zero set with respect to the Lebesgue measure.)

Comment: @user7427029 Done.